# In which non-Sinitic languages do negative clauses retain older constituent order in SVC-derived complex predicates?

Tags: syntax, historical-linguistics, word-order, negation

Many complex predicates are historically derived from serial verb constructions. This is not only true of the Sinitic family. For example, in Saramaccan (Byrne 1987, as cited in Givón 2009):

```
(1) a  bi-fefi   di-wosu   kaba.
    he TNS-paint the-house finish
    He finished painting the house.
```

However, the Chinese constructions are more innovative in that the object has been moved to the end of the sentence, for the most part. Yet in most dialects of modern Chinese except Mandarin, complex predicates also sometimes preserve the older V + O + C order similar to the Saramaccan example in (1). This is most common in negative clauses. (The C is what is traditionally termed a *complement* in Chinese linguistics, but it's more like a *satellite* in Talmy's sense, and is developed from the 'lighter' verb of an asymmetric serial verb construction). An example from Cantonese is (2):

```
(2) nei wan  ngo m   dou
    you find me  NEG arrive
    You cannot find me.
```

My question: I know negative clauses are more conservative in general, but are there specific cases outside the Sinitic branch where object placement in complex predicates is more conservative in negative clauses? Thanks!

Givón, T. (2009). *The genesis of syntactic complexity: Diachrony, ontogeny, neuro-cognition, evolution*. John Benjamins Publishing.